# Bootstrap drop-down is getting hidden below the div and z-index property not working

Tags: html, css

I'm facing an issue with the bootstrap drop-down menu.

The drop-down is available inside a `<thead> <th>` of the table. On click of option-vertical glyphicon it pops down, also it pushes the `<tbody>` down.

[image]

Below is the CSS part of the drop-down code,

```css
position: relative;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
z-index: 1000;
display: none;
float: left;
min-width: 160px;
padding: 5px 0;
margin: 2px 0 0;
list-style: none;
font-size: 14px;
text-align: left;
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
background-clip: padding-box;
```

If CSS Position property of the drop-down changed to absolute, It doesn't push the content down but instead it hides below the table body.

Screenshot for absolute position - Dropdown

[image]

I need the drop-down to overlay the table body and it should not push the contents down.

Comment: Welcome to SO. CSS is useful but it would be much nicer if you could reproduce the issue in a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: Hi @Smollet777 , Thanks I'll update the snippet asap.